# Create thin divider using a 9-patch png

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to create a simple divider using a 9-patch png but I can't seem to get it to stretch correctly. Below is what I have set up on the left and what I want it to do on the right (i scaled it up by 10x to make it easier to see, the real thing is only 16x6 pixels).

[image]

I'm using it as a background on an imageview:

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:src="@drawable/divider"
    android:contentDescription="@string/blank">
```

Here is a screenshot from the app itself:

[image]

Where am I going wrong? 9-patch pngs seem to confuse me each time I try to use them.

Comment: A vertical scale area on the left is required.

Comment: I only want it stretching horizontally though - it will always be 2 dip high regardless of device.

Comment: You can still give it a one pixel scale area. If it's always going to be small, it just won't use it.

Comment: @Geobits - I have changed it to http://i.stack.imgur.com/f0iLi.png but the result is still the same. It won't stretch across like it should be doing.

Comment: Add vertical content area as well.

Comment: Does the file name ends in .9.png ?

Comment: @NemanjaKovačević - yes it does.

Comment: In the image above you have 6px height but in the xml you want it to be 2dp. Dou you have an extra line of white (or transparent) on top and bottom in you original image did you just draw it here for clarity?

Comment: @NemanjaKovačević - good point, it does have a transparent pixel extra on all sides. I will take it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `android:src` to `android:background` in your xml. ImageViews are used for the actual image, and their scaling depends on `scaleType`. They don't scale 9patch images the way you'd think. Using `background` tells it to use it that way.

Side note: You don't even need to use an `ImageView`, just a simple `View` with `background` set will do it.